# Function to determine how many bars I need for different pieces of different sizes

Tags: javascript, function, calculation, mat

I'm trying to create a function that calculates how many 6-meter bars I need for different pieces of different sizes. For example, if I need 3 pieces, each 4 meters long, I obviously need 3 bars, but I can't seem to create a function that does that. Please help.

I tried to create a list and have another function count the leftovers of the iteration based on the input value, but I didn't succeed.

```css
   let trozos = [];
        /*add number of pieces*/
        function agregarTrozos() {
            const numTrozos = parseInt(document.getElementById("trozos").value);
            const tamanoTrozo = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tamano").value);
            
            if (!isNaN(numTrozos) && !isNaN(tamanoTrozo)) {
                for (let i = 0; i < numTrozos; i++) {
                    trozos.push(tamanoTrozo);
                    actualizarListaTrozos();
                }
                document.getElementById("trozos").value = "";
                document.getElementById("tamano").value = "";
            }
        }
        /*update number of chunks*/
        function actualizarListaTrozos() {
            const listaTrozos = document.getElementById("listaTrozos");
            listaTrozos.innerHTML = "";
            trozos.forEach(tamano => {
                const li = document.createElement("li");
                li.textContent = tamano + " meters";
                listaTrozos.appendChild(li);
            });
        }
        /*calculation of necessary bars*/
        function calcularBarras() {
            const longitudBarra = 6;
            let longitudTotal = trozos.reduce((total, tamano) => total + tamano, 0);
            let barrasNecesarias = 0;
            
            while (longitudTotal > 0) {
                barrasNecesarias++;
                longitudTotal -= longitudBarra;
            }
            
            document.getElementById("resultado").textContent = barrasNecesarias;
        }
            /* clean */
        function limpiar() {
            trozos = [];
            actualizarListaTrozos();
            document.getElementById("resultado").textContent = "";
        }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <h1>Bar Calculator</h1>
    <p>Each bar measures 6</p>
    <label for="trozos">Number of Pieces:</label>
    <input type="number" id="trozos">
    <label for="tamano">Piece Size (meters):</label>
    <input type="number" id="tamano">
    <button onclick="agregarTrozos()">Add</button>
    <hr>
    <h2>Metal Pieces</h2>
    <ul id="listaTrozos"></ul>
    <hr>
    <button onclick="calcularBarras()">Calculate Necessary Bars</button>
    <h2>Necessary Bars: <span id="resultado"></span></h2>
    <button onclick="limpiar()">Clean</button>
```

Comment: Your question is really confusing.

What does it mean: "how many 6-meter bars I need for different pieces of different sizes"?. The example you provide doesn't help. 3 pieces, each 4 meters long, why wouldn't you need 2 6-meter bars but you say you need 3?

Comment: @atteggiani it does make sense. Its about getting FULL bars not about cutting up multiple bars and gluing them together. So if each bar is 6 meters long, that means you can only get 1 x 4 meter bar from it with 2 meters left over.

Comment: @imvain2 No, I still don't understand sorry. You say "it's about getting FULL bars" (I presume you refer to the 6-meter bars since the question does not mention any other 'bar'). But then you say "you can only get 1 x 4 meter bar from it". It seems to me you are not considering full bars if you're taking 4 meters from a 6-meter bar.
The question does not make sense as it is posed, sorry.

Comment: Hello, what I want is to get the number of bars I need (each bar measures 6 meters) for 3 pieces of 4 meters each and 5 pieces of 1 meter each.